# How to set the background of a "text line" footline in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I am using the "default" theme with the "crane" color theme and I would like to add a footline to the slides, but with a background color defined by the "crane" color theme.

I have added the necessary text with the following command:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{
      \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-8pt}\inserttitle\hfill\insertauthor\hfill\insertpagenumber}
}
```

In the beamer class documentation, there seem to be different options available for the footline like  "[infolines theme]", but they rely on the specific outer theme to be loaded.

The "infolines" theme adds a header to the slides, that I don't need (and it doesn't seem possible to turn it off?), and I don't want the footer to show the total slide number, just the number of the current slide... hence a "[text line]" with a set background color. Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you could do something like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{crane}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right, rightskip=1mm, leftskip=1mm]{titlelike}
        \inserttitle\hfill\insertauthor\hfill\insertframenumber%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\author{Me}
\title{You}

\begin{document}

\frame{}

\end{document}
```

I used the `titlelike` color for the footer, since crane doesn't define a footer color.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To do that i generally use the following:

```
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{my footline}{
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.5pt,wd=\paperwidth]{footlinecolor}
\hskip2pt
left text
\hspace*{\fill} 
center text
\hspace*{\fill}
\llap{\insertpagenumber\,/\,\insertpresentationendpage\,}
\hskip-2pt
\vskip-0.5pt
\end{beamercolorbox}
}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[my footline]
```

The `hskip` and `vskip` after the page number are just used to fine tune its position. I've left them in case they maybe useful to you.